# Error writing data to Bigquery using Databricks Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, google-bigquery, azure-databricks

I run a daily job to write data to BigQuery using Databricks Pyspark. There was a recent update of configuration for Databricks (https://docs.databricks.com/data/data-sources/google/bigquery.html) which caused the job to fail. I followed all the steps in the docs. Reading data works again but writing throws the following error: `java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFS not found`

I tried adding configuration also right in the code (as advised for similar errors in Spark) but it did not help:

```py
spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set('fs.gs.impl', 'com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystem')
spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set('fs.gs.auth.service.account.enable', 'true')
spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set('google.cloud.auth.service.account.json.keyfile', "<path-to-key.json>")
```

My code is:

```py
upload_table_dataset = 'testing_dataset'
upload_table_name = 'testing_table'
upload_table = upload_table_dataset + '.' + upload_table_name

(import_df.write.format('bigquery') 
  .mode('overwrite') 
  .option('project', 'xxxxx-test-project')
  .option('parentProject', 'xxxxx-test-project')
  .option('temporaryGcsBucket', 'xxxxx-testing-bucket') 
  .option('table', upload_table) 
  .save()
)
```

Comment: There probably was a bug in Azure Databricks which was later corrected. The daily job works again (using a code with same structure as in the question).

Answer (score 0):

You need to [install the GCS connector](https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/hadoop-connectors/blob/master/gcs/INSTALL.md) on your cluster first

Comment: Do you know what this means in Databricks? Do I need to install some library? Do I need to set some configuration in code or on cluster? I don't know how to work with Hadoop in Databricks other than some in-code configuration and so I was not able to follow the linked documentation. Thank you.